# Assigning colour to QGIS vector layer fields?

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I have a vector layer with a field called "dBM".

through query builder, I am hoping to change change the colour of the point depending on the value of "dBM".

e.g.

```
 "dBM" more than 20 ----> change colour of point to green

 "dBM" less than 20 ----> change colour to yellow

 "dBM" less than 0  ----> change colour to red
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider doing it with a data defined override in the styling of that layer.

This is done by opening the properties window for the layer and (1) clicking *Style*, (2) clicking *Simple marker*, (3) clicking the *E* xpression button beside *Fill*, (4) clicking *Edit...* and creating an expression to assign a colour based on the value in the field you want.

[image: qgis setting a colour based on field value]

The expression can be expanded from what @Jesse McMillan proposed:

```
CASE
  WHEN "dBM" <= 0 THEN '255,0,0'
  WHEN "dBM" > 0 AND "dBM" <= 20 THEN '255,255,0'
  ELSE '0,255,0'
END
```

Not sure what shades of red, yellow and green you like, but that should be a decent starting point.

Comment: a useful add-on to this kind of styling is using the new color variables. under document properties > default styles you can name specific colors. For instance you could have 'dBM red', 'dBM yellow', and 'dBM green'. You could then use `project_color('dBM red')` instead of `255,0,0`

Comment: @SaultDon I get an error like this: Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected $end

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly straightforward thing to do, and there are many ways to accomplish it.

In the layer properties dialog, open the style tab. Change the style from "single symbol" to "rule-based"

Hit the plus until you have three styles. To change the rule associated with one double click it. Here are some rule examples:

Less than zero

```
    "dBM" <= 0
```

Less than 20

```
    "dBM" > 0 and "dBM" <= 20
```

21 or more

```
  "dBM" > 20
```

You could also use the categorized type style