# Colour coding vector layers?

Tags: qgis, style, expression

Based on a [previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176220/assigning-colour-to-qgis-vector-layer-fields), I tried to implement this in the expressions tab:

```
CASE
  WHEN "dBM" <= 0 THEN '255,0,0'
  WHEN "dBM" > 0 AND "dBM" <= 20 THEN '255,255,0'
  ELSE '0,255,0'
```

However, I get an error like this:

`Parser Error: syntax error, unexpected $end Eval Error: No root node! Parsing failed?`

Desperately need this to work...

Answer (score 6):

Just tested (QGIS 2.8). It works if you add a `END` statement at the end, like that:

```
CASE
  WHEN "dBM" <= 0 THEN '255,0,0'
  WHEN "dBM" > 0 AND "dBM" <= 20 THEN '255,255,0'
  ELSE '0,255,0'
END
```